# Can (singular) homology classes always be represented by images of closed manifolds?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

My intuition tells me that if $A \in H_2(M;\mathbf Z)$, then $A$ can be represented by a map $\Sigma \to M$, where $\Sigma$ is a closed (= compact boundaryless) surface, i.e., the connected sum of tori or of real projective planes. It would then seem that, in general, any $B \in H_k(M;\mathbf Z)$ can be represented by a map [closed $k$-manifold] $\to M$.

This is probably something really trivial but I'm not sure how to go about proving it "properly."

A representative of a homology class in $H_k(M;\mathbf Z)$ is a $k$-cycle, i.e., a formal linear combination ($\mathbf Z$ coefficients) of maps [$k$-simplex] $\to M$ such that the boundary is empty. So this can be viewed as a map [disjoint union of $k$-simplices] $\to M$ such that "the boundaries of the simplices get quotiented out." Thus, we can factor this map into [disjoint union of $k$-simplices] $\to$ [closed $k$-manifold] $\to M$, where the first map is just gluing the boundaries of the simplices together.

All this seems very hand-wavy to me and I'm not really convinced by my own pseudo-argument. Any help to make this more rigorous (or point out the fallacies!) would be appreciated.

Comment: You need orientations or else you don't have a fundamental class integrally. (So no real projective planes.)

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1489/cohomology-and-fundamental-classes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a classical problem in algebraic topology, the [Steenrod problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steenrod_problem), which was more or less solved by Thom. Thom showed that this is true

- $\bmod 2$,
- rationally, and
- integrally if $k \le 6$.

Integrally for $k \ge 7$ there are counterexamples; the obstructions involve [Steenrod operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steenrod_algebra) for odd primes. (It's harder to glue a bunch of simplices into a manifold than you're making it sound!) See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1489/cohomology-and-fundamental-classes) and [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21171/when-is-a-homology-class-represented-by-a-submanifold) for more details, as well as [this overview](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2004-41-03/S0273-0979-04-01026-2/) of Thom's work by Sullivan.

Comment: That's very interesting. (+1).

Comment: How smooth is the construction of the integral classes for $k \leq 6$? (Is Thom's proof even a construction?) For instance, might you end up representing some cohomology class by a non-smoothable (but still triangulable!) manifold?

Comment: @Mike: I don't think it's a construction. I haven't read the paper, but I expect it's a homotopy-theoretic calculation involving oriented bordism. Classes in oriented bordism are always represented by smooth manifolds.

Comment: Sullivan's survey is very helpful; thanks for editing it in.