Reason elements of higher dimensional homology groups fail to be orientable manifolds
In the subsection titled "Singular Homology" in section 2.1, Hatcher constructs a $\delta$-complex $K_\xi$ from a chain $\xi$ by writing $\xi = \Sigma \ \epsilon_i \sigma_i$ where $\epsilon_i = \pm 1$ and repetition of the singular n-simplices $\sigma_i$ is allowed. $K_\xi$ is then taken to be the maximal collection of such canceling pairs.
Hatcher goes on to say that the $\sigma_i$'s induce a map from $K_\xi$ to $X$. Further, if $\xi$ is a cycle, then $K_\xi$ is and a "oriented manifold away from its nonmanifold points" (not sure what this means at all).
He concludes the introduction by stating that elements of $H_1(X)$ are loops in X and boundaries are maps of loops such can "extended to a map of an oriented surface into X. He says that analogous statements hold for $H_2(X)$. That is cycles are closed orientable surfaces and that cycles are boundaries iff said surfaces can be extended to an orientable volume.
Finally, Hatcher says that this does not hold for higher dimension. Can anyone explain why we do not expect higher dimensional cycles to be closed submanifolds of X? I am alright with a heuristic explanation if a rigorous one is above my pay grade.
Note: If the construction above is relevant to explanation, it should be noted that I am pretty shaking on what he's doing because Hatcher provides virtually only the details I have included which I would characterize as unclear.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steenrod_problem

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1301084/can-singular-homology-classes-always-be-represented-by-images-of-closed-manifo
